# Visual Studio 2019 Miscellaneous Files

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a project within a solution and every class I try to open within that project opens up as `Miscellaneous Files`

[image].

There's nothing different about this project to any other projects in the same solution.

This is very annoying as I can't check out definiton of methods there's no intellisense nothing. However I can build the solution just fine.

As a workaround I'm opening the solution in Visual Studio 2017, where it works fine. I used to fix this by deleting the whole solution and getting it from source code again, but latelly that doesnt help either.

Comment: Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.  Lots of existing bug reports about it, add your own if you have a good cue to what might cause this problem.  Seems they need some.

Comment: I have no idea why is this happening, had a look at the proj file to compare it with one that is working (the test proj for the same) but I couldn't see anything outstanding.

Comment: @IgorMeszaros: Did you manage to find a solution to this problem? If so, it would be great if you could post a short answer. I am having this problem with a Windows Service application, the other applications in the project are working fine. This also only started happening recently, used to work fine and no obvious changes have been made.

Comment: @musefan unfortunately I didn't find a solution... it went away with a reinstall if I remember right... it was 2 years ago so don't remember any more. Sorry...